# Focusing on text is not working using asp.net web appln

Tags: asp.net, ajax

In the below code i have a textbox when i focus on textbox it should call the server side function and no alert msg is coming pls help me to solve the issue .And i add the web service refernce.Pls anyone help me to find and solve the issue.

focus.ascx:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%=txtField.ClientID%>").bind("focus", function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<%=Request.FilePath%>/txtField_GotFocus",
                data: "{foo:'whatever'}",
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg); 
                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="frm" runat="server">
<asp:TextBox ID="txtField" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" ClientIDMode="Static"  ></asp:TextBox></form>
</body></html>
```

focus.ascx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace focus_demo
{
    public partial class focus : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        [WebMethod]
        public static string txtField_GotFocus()
        {
            string foo = HttpContext.Current.Request["foo"];

            return "awesome, it works!";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the Below step and you will get your required output

### **Ajax function Call**

```
function CallAjaxRequest() { 
    var Simplefailuredata = {};
    Simplefailuredata.Id = 1;
    Simplefailuredata.Comments = 'Comments-1';
    Simplefailuredata.Score = 500.25;
    Simplefailuredata.Adjustment = 700.25;
    Simplefailuredata.ShutdownData = new Array();
    Simplefailuredata.ShutdownData[0] = new Object({ Id: 2, Description: "Desc-1",  CausedShutdown: true, ShutdownType: "ShutdownType-1" });
    Simplefailuredata.ShutdownData[1] = new Object({ Id: 5, Description: "Desc-2", CausedShutdown: false, ShutdownType: "ShutdownType-2" });
    var object = JSON.stringify({ simplefailuredata: Simplefailuredata });
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default2.aspx/GetResponse",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: object,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false
    });
}


<form id="form1" runat="server">
 <div>
 <input type="button" id="btn"  value ="t" onfocus="CallAjaxRequest();"   />
 </div>
</form>
```

### **Code Behind**

```
public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string GetResponse(simplefailuredata simplefailuredata)
{
    return "";
}
}



public class simplefailuredata 
{ 
public int Id; 
public string Comments; 
public double Score; 
public double Adjustment; 
public List<shutdownData> ShutdownData; 
} 

public class shutdownData 
{ 
public int Id { get; set; } 
public string Description { get; set; } 
public bool CausedShutdown { get; set; }
public string ShutdownType { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: i want to call server side by focus not by clicking in asp:textbox

Answer (score 0):

Things to note on the client-side. If the `ClientIdMode` property of the textbox is set to `Static` then you don't need the server-side expression. Also `<%=Request.FilePath%>` will give you the physical path of the web page, not the url of the page. You need to set the content type of the ajax request. Change the javascript code to...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#txtField").bind("focus", function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/path_if_any/page.aspx/txtField_GotFocus",
            data: "{'foo':'whatever'}",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.d); 
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Then the page method is expecting an object with property named `foo`. This object can be...

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string foo{get;set;}
}
```

and finally change the page method signature to receive the above-mentioned object...

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string txtField_GotFocus(MyObject obj)
    {
        string foo = obj.foo;

        return "awesome, it works!";
    }
```

Comment: i get no alert and it is not working.pls check my url "focus.ascx/txtField_GotFocus"

Comment: The url should reference your web page instead of your user control